# Flutter Speech-to-text package not recognizing single words like 'yes' but recognizing 'yes please', 'yes of course'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

our mobile app has a voice asssistant which has lot if usecases to ask confirmation from user. where they say 'yes' to confirm. but weirdly it doesnt take the word 'yes' but takes 'yes please'. we cannot force user to say 'yes please' or 'yes of course' or 'yes proceed'. what could be the reason is there anything we are missing ? below is the config

```
  listenFor: Duration(seconds: 60),
  pauseFor: Duration(seconds: 20),
  //listenMode: spd.ListenMode.dictation,
  cancelOnError: false,
  partialResults: true,
  localeId: 'en-IN')
```

Comment: Seems an issue is filed, but still no reply : https://github.com/csdcorp/speech_to_text/issues/421

Comment: yes @AVEbrahimi I only filed an issue. yet to get response